# Cisco wrv210 static IP behind comcast router too slow

Tags: firewall, cisco, router

So I subscribed to a Comcast business account (cable internet provider) and put a Cisco WRV210 in front of the Comcast modem. They gave me 1 static IP address which i'm planning to use to access my camera system.

I configured the DMZ to translate the static IP address to a local one and go straight to the video server. This allows me to access the static IP in the network. This was setup 2 days ago and I've noticed the connection keeps getting slower and slower until the point where I have to reboot the cisco firewall box. Upon further investigation, when i plug my laptop into the Comcast router, I receive an IP address of 10.1.10.1 which tells me the router also has DHCP enabled. the Comcast cable modem is a SMC brand.

Is this supposed to enabled? I hope I don't have to return the Cisco box and get something else.

Comment: 10.1.10.1 is the IP address of the SMC ---piece of crap--- cable modem/router. So your question is really unclear here. Though you can always login to it with the default username/password and reconfigure it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call up Comcast and ask them to disable DHCP on the router, though I'm not sure why you think DHCP is related to your connection problems (and I doubt it is), but without a lot more specific information, I don't see how anyone's going to be able to give you an answer on why (or for that matter, even *if*) your connection's slowing down.

Comment: I agree. The fact that the cable modem has a DHCP server enabled (which is perfectly normal) is completely irrelevant to the problem. If it does turn out to be relevant I'll eat my shoe, unless the Mayan apocalypse actually happens, in which case I'll be working on my tan.